# copy Path in file writer Class into File Class

Tags: java, file

I would like to create a new file using filewriter class and use the exact path in file class (don't want to copy/paste the manually, any changes in file writer path, we would like to reflect the instances) to get absolute path of the particular file. Can anyone suggest me how?

First I would create a filewriter and later want to use File to display it's attributes such that any chnages in Fiewriter URL would be displayed.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class files_read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

try {
FileWriter FW=new FileWriter("C:/Users/91870/Downloads/Boss.txt");

FW.write("yoyo");
FW.close();
File f=new File(FW);

}
catch(IOException ie)

{
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    ie.printStackTrace();
}

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, you have some `path` in some `file` and you want to extract that `path` and create new `file` on that path?

Comment: Actually the i want to display the Path available in file writer and i have updated code to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around. First create the `File` instance and then the `FileWriter` with that `File` instance.

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/91870/Downloads/Boss.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
...
```

Comment: Why cant we do it other way around, if possible can u pls explain which would be helpful

Comment: Look at the [FileWriter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html). There is no method to get the filename out of a FileWriter instance. The file name or File instance is only a FileWriter constructor parameter. If you need the file name later you have to store it elsewhere.

Comment: Additionally, you should know that the `File` class is outdated. Now it is recommended to use the [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package's `Path` together with `Paths` and `Files`.